# Why can't I run the following method from a generic object?

Tags: c#, generics, syntax

I am (trying) to learn about generics and I thought I understood them. I have the following code for the generic class:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// generics
    /// </summary>
    class Point<T> where T : IConvertible
    {
        public T X;


        NumberFormatInfo nf = NumberFormatInfo.CurrentInfo;

        public double Subtract(Point<T> pt)
        {
            return (X.ToDouble(nf) + pt.X.ToDouble(nf));
        }

    }
```

and in the `Main()`, I can create the objects fine:

```
        Point<int> pt = new Point<int>();
        Point<double> pt2 = new Point<double>();
        Point<string> pt3 = new Point<string>();

        pt.X = 10;

        pt2.X = 10;

        pt3.X = "10";
```

Now, I can run the `Subtract` Method on two `int`s, `double`s or even `string`s, but I can't run on mixed, which I thought I would be able to because of the `.ToDouble` conversion.

If I try to run `Console.WriteLine(pt.Subtract(pt2));` I get the following errors:

```
Error   1   The best overloaded method match for Date.Point<int>.Subtract(Date.Point<int>)' has some invalid arguments

Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Date.Point<double>' to 'Date.Point<int>'
```

The code itself is not so important as I am simply trying to understand/learn generics, so I would just like to understand what is wrong here and why it wouldn't work.... The actual method is not that important/will not be used.

Comment: Could you add the piece of code which doesn't work please?

Comment: The second question I have started with "I thought I understood..." Lol, I will get there in the end... and @Steven - Updated.

Comment: I **know** the code isn't important and I **know** this is just for learning purposes, but `Subtract` is definitely not `+` :P

Comment: @BoltClock :P I realise... genuine error, but I don't think I actually ran it once, I was just trying to get it to compile and learn why/how to get it to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method signature:

```
public double Subtract(Point<T> pt)
```

Asks for a `Point` of generic type `T`, which matches the generic type in your class definition:

```
class Point<T> where T : IConvertible
```

That means it's asking for the same type.

You can specify a different generic type to allow it to mix different types:

```
public double Subtract<U>(Point<U> pt) where U : IConvertible
{
    return (X.ToDouble(nf) + pt.X.ToDouble(nf));
}
```

Note, however, that since the actual type of `U` can be inferred from the `Point<U>` argument you pass, you can call your method in the same way without needing to specify the type:

```
Console.WriteLine(pt.Subtract(pt2)); // As opposed to pt.Subtract<double>(pt2)
```

Comment: This works great and I understand what is happening (up to a point) - I understand the Point<u> part starting a new generic, but I don't understand the reasoning behind Subtract<U>. Can you explain what is happening here.

Comment: @Wil: I introduce a new generic type `U` to this method, so I have to make the method a generic method of `U`. Without the first `<U>`, `Subtract()` is just `Subtract<T>()`, which can't accept any other generic types.

Comment: I feel like an idiot... I really understand what is going on, but not why... If the method is being renamed Subtract<U>, why don't you need to rename the call from pt.Subtract(pt2) to pt.Subtract<x>(pt2) or similar... Are there any good resource you can point me to so I don't have to ask a load of silly questions?

Comment: @Wil: What takes place then is known as *type inference*. The `Subtract` method can tell what generic type `pt2` is, and act accordingly. The only resource that comes to my mind right now is MSDN docs...

Comment: Sorry... Again, Thanks for getting it to work - at the moment, the problem is, I understand the method needing the Point<U> pt, so that pt can be anything and not the same as the original class, I just don't see why it is needed on Subtract as surely the method call would be the same no matter int, double or other... I guess this is just going to be one of those things that I know the problem and how to get working, but just not why it works!... I will have a read of MSDN

Comment: Ok... A method that uses generics is called a generic method and it is written like that... Now I have read MSDN, in combination with your answer, it makes a LOT of sense, sorry for the noobish questions, hopefully there will not be many more!

Answer (score 6):

Your `Subtract` method takes a `Point<T>`.
`T` here is the type parameter of your class, which means that it can only take a `Point` of the same type.

You need to give `Subtract` a separate generic parameter so that it can take a `Point<U>` for any `U`.

Answer (score 1):

The type `T` must be the same in the class declaration and the method:

```
class Point<T> where T : IConvertible
{
    public double Subtract(Point<T> pt)
```

You could introduce a second generic parameter:

```
class Point<T> where T : IConvertible
{
    public double Subtract<T2>(Point<T2> pt) where T2 : IConvertible
```